# run gulp-clean-css options in gulp-inline

Tags: gulp, gulp-clean-css

How do I go about configuring options for a nested plugin in gulp?
I have a gulp task that uses gulp-inline to inline any css and js.

gulp-inline has options to set a css processor

```
gulp.task('html', function () {

  gulp.src(source + '**/*.+(html|php)')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.inline({
        base: source,
        js: $.uglify,
        css: $.cleanCss,
        disabledTypes: ['svg', 'img']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
});
```

Ideally when running the task I'd like to declare config options for the css and js

```
gulp.task('html', function () {

  gulp.src(source + '**/*.+(html|php)')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.inline({
        base: source,
        js: $.uglify,
        css: $.cleanCss({
            keepBreaks: false,
            advanced: false,
            keepSpecialComments: '*',
            aggressiveMerging: false
        }),
        disabledTypes: ['svg', 'img']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass a function that returns the `cleanCss` transform:

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
  gulp.src(source + '**/*.+(html|php)')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.inline({
        base: source,
        js: $.uglify,
        css: function() {
          return $.cleanCss({ /* options */ });
        },
        disabledTypes: ['svg', 'img']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(build))
});
```